# Crystal Reports Direct Print in web based Client System - File Hosted in Server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Last one week i am searching for direct print option for crystal report ASPx .net(C#). But not getting proper answer,How to solve this problem.Can anyone knows or have any ideas please tell.ASAP 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

oReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1,true,0,0);